# Different ways on how to manipulate access database in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm currently using system.data.oledb but I can't seem to make the update , search, & delete work fine.
Are there any other ways on  how to manipulate an ms access database in vb.net easier than my method?
Here is my code for searching:

```
      Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=F:\ACCESS DATABASE\search.mdb")       
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select * from GH where IDNUMBER= '" &  TextBox12.Text & "' ", cn)

    cn.Open()

    Dim rdr As OleDbDataReader
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader




    If rdr.HasRows Then
        rdr.Read()
        NoAcc = rdr("IDNUMBER")
        If (TextBox12.Text = NoAcc) Then TextBox13.Text = rdr("NAME")
        If (TextBox12.Text = NoAcc) Then TextBox14.Text = rdr("DEPARTMENT")
        If (TextBox12.Text = NoAcc) Then TextBox15.Text = rdr("COURSE")
```

Then you will have to make the necessary changes before pressing update:
This is the update code, which is defective(it really updates the data but then it will duplicate the previous data, and the updated data will have a different id number):

```
        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)


    ds.Tables("GH").Rows(INC).Item("NAME") = TextBox13.Text
    ds.Tables("GH").Rows(INC).Item("DEPARTMENT") = TextBox14.Text
    ds.Tables("GH").Rows(INC).Item("COURSE") = TextBox15.Text

    da.Update(ds, "GH")

        MsgBox("Data updated")
```

Comment: Can you share some code that you have tried and that failed?

Comment: If you don't get it working with oledb, what makes you believe you will be more successful with other APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call DAO code through com interop in vb.net. The DAO interface is designed to work with the JET database engine directly so in most cases offers better performance than using ado.net or ADO however it does tie you into JET to some degree.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this one for the update

```
    If nameoftable.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
        nameoftable.Rows(recordposition)("course_code") = textbox1.Text
        nameoftable.Rows(recordposition)("course_description") = textbox2.Text
        nameofyouradapter.Update(nameoftable)
    End If
```